# Detect if specific node.js script is running from bash

Tags: node.js, bash, cron

**Read as:** *Detect (if specific node.js script is running) from bash*.

---

I have a server that runs a specific node.js script on certain actions and certain `cron` intervals.

The script might take a few hours to finish, but is not supposed to run more than once at the same time.

Is there a way in `sh` or `bash` to detect if the specific script is already running?

---

#### process

Simply running (if) `pidof node` won't work, because there might be other unrelated node scripts running.

#### pidfile

The closest half solution I can think of is `touch /tmp/nodescript.lock` and only run the script if it does not exist. But apparently `/tmp` doesn't (always) get cleaned on a server crash/reboot.

#### secret option number 3

Perhaps there's some other simple way I'm not aware of. Maybe I can give a process some kind of static identifier, which is gone when the process is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

When you invoke a script with nodejs, it appears in the process list such as:

```
user       773 68.5  7.5 701904 77448 pts/0    Rl+  09:49   0:01 nodejs scriptname.js
```

So you could simply check `ps` for its existence with a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="scriptname.js" # nodejs script's name here
RUN=`pgrep -f $NAME`

if [ "$RUN" == "" ]; then
 echo "Script is not running"
else
 echo "Script is running"
fi
```

Adjust it up to your needs and put into cron.

Comment: `grep | grep` is not very smart. Use `pgrep` of `ps auxw | grep '[n]ame'`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Also, I've just found out that `pgrep -f 'scriptname.js'` is quite enough.

Comment: And please, stop using backquotes but `$( )`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use a robust *lock mechanism* like this :

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 9>/path/to/lock/file
if ! flock -n 9  ; then
   echo "another instance of $0 is running";
   exit 1
fi

node arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

Now, only one instance of a node script can be run at once

Comment: What does `exec 9` do? Do I need to remove the lock afterwards?

Comment: This assign file descriptor 9 to the file. No need to do anything at the end of the script. The file descriptor will be removed automatically

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and I ended up with a completely NodeJS based solution.

I used this awesome module named **[ps-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ps-node)**.

You can look up if a specific process is already running before you fire up your code.

```
ps.lookup({
    command: 'node',
    arguments: 'your-script.js',
},
function(err, resultList){
    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
    // check if the same process already running:
    if (resultList.length > 1){
        console.log('This script is already running.');
    }
    else{
        console.log('Do something!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting module `ps`. You need to be sure of the target server before using this method however. On some systems the command is `nodejs` and arguments may differ. Also different apps all have their entrypoint named `index.js`.

Comment: Yes this is true. I managed this problem by passing a unique argument at that certain script and execute it like **node my-script.js my_custom_arg**. Obviously at **ps.lookup** I search for that custom argument not the name of the script file. I even think command parameter is not required to search processes with **ps** however im not sure about this.